# What to do for J1 visa in case of passport theft?

Tags: usa, passports, j1-visas, lost-documents

Recently my girlfriend's Indian passport got stolen. It contained a very important J1 US visa. We are slightly panicky since the application took three months to process and the travel day is 20th Jan 2018. She is living in Austria and can get a temporary passport issued within an hour from the Indian consulate.

As per my understanding of this things, this will void her previous passport, correct?

But then what happens to the visa? Can it be simply reissued on the temporary passport after producing the FIR?

Unfortunately, the state.gov website does not provide any clear direction as to how existing visas can be reissued in case of theft or loss.

It would be helpful if someone can provide some additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to hear this.

She'll need to [report the stolen visa to the US consulate](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html) via email. The information required is listed on that page. The [contact info for the Vienna Embassy](https://at.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/) can be found online.

I would make the report immediately, advising them of the urgency of the situation and requesting a replacement visa. They will take the report and advise on the local procedures, arranging for her to come to the consular section for a new visa. Unfortunately, it may not be possible to get the replacement processed in time, as there are just two working days left, so I'd start making preliminary plans in case it is necessary to delay her trip.

Comment: Above all, if she cannot fly, request a refund of the airport taxes. They're **always** refundable and can be quite a bit.